# Broadcast receiver not detecting keyevents

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, keyevent

I am trying to receive Power button events in my app. I have added the following code in my Manifest file and then displaying a toast in receive method of the broadcast receiver class but still the code is not working. Am I missing something?

```
 <receiver android:name="com.xxxxx">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"></action>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

yeah what you want to do is possible just few things I want to clear out, showing toast while screen is off is no use also detecting power button and screen state is the same and I'll show you how to detect screen state and show toast only, but the power button I still don't know the way to detect it since power button is only managed by System, I think you'll need root to adjust or add functions to power button. any way here is the code you'll need:

1 - you'll need an activity that can start/stop detecting screen state, a service that keeps your app working in background, lastly the Broadcastreceiver. so from the activity you should start service :

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, yourservice.class));
```

make sure to stop it after you are done

```
stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, yourservice.class));
```

2- here how your service should look like :

```
public class yourservice extends Service{
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    this.mReceiver = new your receiver();
    this.registerReceiver(this.mReceiver, filter);
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
if (yourbroasdcast.screenOff) {
            //here screen is off do your stuff
    } else {
            //here screen is on do your stuff example your toast
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "write your toast here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

3 - your broadcasrtreceiver :

```
public class yourbroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static boolean screenOff;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = true;
    }else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(context, yourservice.class);
    i.putExtra("screen state", screenOff);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

}

4 - the manifest should look like this

```
<service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".yourservice"/>
    <receiver android:name=".yourbroadcast" android:enabled="true">  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

hope I helped... if you needed anything just ask me :)